# How to integrate code editor in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, codemirror, ace-editor

I have tried every possible popular code editor from npm but all of them **refuse to display monospace fonts.** I have tried ThemeProvider and inline style but it doesn't work. **It displays phantom monospace fonts and actual font displayed is the default one.** Apart from the code editor, monospace works in the Typography component. Apart from the font, all code editors work fine. Please help.

Comment: My friend sorry for old solution. i updated solution connectedCallback() function is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Shadow Root

With shadow root you can isolate from root css design. For documentation, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM

```
window.customElements.define('codemirror', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        // !! Shadow Root inside css rules you can change this
        shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
            <style>
               @import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.24.2/codemirror.min.css)
            </style>` 
        // !! on ready you can change yourself CodeMirror constructor
        this.cm = CodeMirror(this.shadowRoot, {lineNumbers: true});        
    }
    
});
```

### HTML

Use custom element
`<codemirror id="test"></codemirror>`;

### JS

get CodeMirror object from *element*.cm

```
var code = document.getElementById("test");
code.cm.setValue("var i = 0;");
```